# Input Buttons won't go below textarea form

Tags: html, css

In basic HTML and CSS, I'm trying to place the submit and reset input buttons below a textarea. I've looked everywhere and wasn't able to find anything similar.

Essentially when I don't add all of the break tags, the buttons are above the textarea (and cover the text, but that's because their div class has an absolute attribute for its position). If I don't have the absolute position, the buttons will center themselves below the nav bar.

I'm quite confused on why this is happening, in regards to both the fact that it centers without the absolute attribute, along with the fact that the buttons don't go below the textarea without the line breaks. Any help would be much appreciated (my guess is it has to do with CSS, but I'm not sure why).

http://jsfiddle.net/2efr8/

```
<!doctype.html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge"/>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
 <head>
   <title> Comments </title> 
<link href= "/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
<style>
        textarea
        {
        margin-top: 15px;
        float:left;
        resize: none;
        }
        .comment_form
        {
        margin-top:15px;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        Color: #DEDBA7;
        margin-bottom:15px;
        }
        .button {
        float: left;
        margin-top:15px;
        position: absolute;
        }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header> <h1> Comments </h1> </header>
    <div class="nav_bar">
          <div class="comment">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="homeLink">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html" class="aboutLink">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html" class="projectLink">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="/eric/blog.html" class="blogLink">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ops/comment.html" class="commentLink">Feedback</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ops/links.html" class="linksLink">Links</a></li>
         </div>
        </div>
<br>
<br>

  <p> Feel free to leave a comment below, don't expect anyone to read it though...
  </p>
  <form name="comment"  method="post" >
<!-- First off should probably use some AJAX or PHP to get this somewhere, Eventually this needs to be a get to the webserver to go into a psql base -->
<p> <div class="comment_form"> Enter your comment below: </p>
<p><textarea  name="comment" cols="50" rows="5"> </textarea>
</p>
</div>
<p>
<div class="button">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type ="submit" value="Submit" onclick='alert("Thanks for your input, we&#39ll make sure to keep it in mind")' />
<input type="reset" value="Erase Comment" />
</div>
</p>
</form>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/* This is a comment, and the main style sheet */

/* reset browser styles */

html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
}
body {
        line-height: 1.2;
}
ol {
        padding-left: 1.4em;
        list-style: decimal;
}
ul {
        padding-left: 1.4em;
        list-style: square;
}
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
}
/* end reset browser styles */

body {
 background-color: #1F7872;
 border: 3px solid rgb(0,0,0);
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px #1D4C4F;
 width: 80%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding: 10px 15px 0px 15px;
 padding-bottom: 80%;
}



header { height: 50px;
         background-color:  #1A202C;
         padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     border-left: 100px;
     border-right: 100px;
         border-bottom: 2px solid #000;     
     margin-right: -15px;
     margin-left: -15px;

     text-align: center;
                }
        h1 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
        font-family: Arial;
/*        margin-top: 7px; */
    color: aqua;
/*  border-right: 1000px;
    border-left: 1000px; */
        }


html{
 background-color: #1A202C;
}
p{
 color: #DEDBA7;
}
h2{
 padding-top: 20px;
 color: #DEDBA7;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

a {
 color: #FF00FF;
}

.nav_bar {
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: -17px;
  list-style: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left; 
  padding-left: 16%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;  
}


.nav_bar li {
 float: left;
 width: 8em;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav_bar a {
  color: aqua;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  /* border-left: none; */
  padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;  
  display: block;
  /*background-color: #E7E7E7; */
  background-color: #1A202C;

  /*
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 2px;
  */
}

.nav_bar a:hover {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 6px 5px 6px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FF00FF;
  background-color: #DEDBA7;
}



.home .homeLink,
.about .aboutLink,
.project .projectLink,
.blog .blogLink,
.comment .commentLink,
.links .linksLink
{
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 6px 5px 6px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1A202C;
}

.tline {
  margin-left: -15px;  
}
```

Comment: cheating the filter using bit.ly is a bad idea! Post the code.. using `Ctrl + K`

Answer (score 0):

Your .button is set to position: absolute; - this means that its position will ignore any other object and be forced to show exactly where you told it to. You didn't specify any position, so it displays on top.

Just get rid of that line from the CSS.

Comment: For some reason it seemed to fix it in jsfiddle, but not on my actual site.. [link](http://telescopium.us/ops/comment.html) Any advice?

Comment: also, even with just getting rid of that line, it will position the buttons in the center, even though i specify it to float left, i'm also confused on that?